# Getting the last updated user by comparing date and time

Tags: java

I am getting list of information along with the user details from an API. Based on a particular parameter i need to get last modified user who has acted upon it by comparing date.

For ex:

**parameter**    **Last updated user**               **Date**

```
 param1          John                     26-Sep-16
 param1          Jane                     12-Nov-17
 Param1          James                   12-April-18
```

The size of the data increases for the same param1 in the list. So how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what do you need: to modify API? to filter out results of API? what `param1` and provided in example names means?
Could you please add some code you have to make it more clear?

Comment: I concur with Dmytro in terms of problem presentation.  Is param1 a combination of String & Date?  By increasing do you mean chronologically or in mem size or data pool?  And code excerpt would also help others help you.   Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question properly, but if what you need is to get the object with the latest modified date from the list of user information entries, then (if you use Java 8+) you may try using Java stream for that as following:

```
list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(UserInformation::getLastModifiedDate));
```

I am assuming here you have a list of `UserInfromation` objects called `list` , and  `UserInfromation` has a getter method with the signature `Date getLastModifiedDate()`

Comment: Actually Param1 is a search string.The API returns  every row with param1,  last updated by, date information etc as list . Each row has different information about param1, so it returns each row as a list. There might be hundred's of list. From these multiple list i want check who edited the param1 information ie, last updated by . Now once filter is applied obviously it will result in to single list as i have compared based on date